# Parse Crash Reporting - symbol file not found, symbols not understood

Tags: ios, parse-platform, crash-reports

I've read through a number of similar questions here about Parse Crash Reporting, and got a couple of hints that helped. But I am still unable to get the symbol file uploaded.

I added the script to XCode exactly as per instructions on the Parse Website. When the app builds, the script seems to run, and all the right messages are being displayed. 
[image]

and

[image]

I added the time-delayed forced Exception to the app, in the suggested place. I ensured that CrashReporting was enabled. I added the Parse framework to the project via CocoaPods; it's there, and the app compiles without error or warning. I did the sequence of one crash, restart, second crash, wait a few minutes, refresh the Parse Dashboard.

But Parse thinks otherwise:
[image]

OK, fine. So i did a manual push of the file, via CLI from Terminal. First attempt failed because I wasn't uploading the DWARF file. Corrected that. Now it says it cant' find the file or directory.

Here's my folder on my machine, where the file is located:

[image]

And here's the command line, with the command and result:

[image]

So the CLI maybe is thinking that the filename isn't a file; I tried changing the name by adding a ".bin" extension.

Then I got a different error: "Do not understand symbol files at:" followed by the full path to the file. I even tried enclosing the full path in single quotes, inside the double quotes; same not-found error.

I have the latest Parse CLI downloaded. I am running the command "parse symbols -p " from the app's Cloud Code directory (an existing directory that had been set up earlier to use other Parse Cloud Code features).

What else to add? Running XCode 6.4, Objective-C app, I checked various other Build Settings to ensure that symbols were being generated. The file is 30Mb in size and opening it reveals what is clearly a binary file, whose contents do look like they're symbols from a compiler - recognizable names of classes, etc.

This is just a test app, and I'm testing out the Parse crash reporting, rather than signing up for another service, like New Relic or any of the other ones; I figure, I'm using Parse for other stuff, why not use its Crash Reporting...

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I just can't see it.

Comment: Why are you on Xcode 6.3?  Why aren't you on Xcode 6.4?  Or Xcode 7?  And why are you trying to use Parse's symbolication tool instead of Xcode's built-in symbolication tools?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I AM on 6.4; typing mistake, and corrected now. I don't know about Xcode's built-in symbolication tools - this is my first Xcode / iOS / Objective-C project, so I have lots to learn still.

So how would Xcode's built-in symbolication tools help? I am just following the directions that Parse provides for its Crash Reporting service. So I am not in a position to be opinionated about other approaches. I am trying to implement crash reporting, that's all.

If you can suggest another approach, then please do.

Comment: There are four things you need to symbolicate a crash log: 1) the crash log itself, 2) the dSYM file that Xcode generate when you built your app (must be the one that Xcode made when you made the build that has crashed), 3) the actual app binary that was made when you made the build that has actually crashed, 4) the device symbols from the specific device and operating system that crashed (so if the crash was on a 4s running 9.0.1, you need device symbols from any 4s running 9.0.1).

Comment: The last thing from this list is optional, but without it you end up with only a partially symbolicated report.

Comment: @nhgrif - thanks, that's good to know. For some future time. Right now, my problem is getting Parse Crash Reporting to work. That was what my question is about. I did invite you to suggest another approach, and you did, and thanks for that.

But my current problem needs to be solved. I don't want to debate pros and cons of Parse vs. other schemes. I just want to solve my Parse issue.

Thanks for your time and insights - appreciated!

Comment: What I am trying to do is even understand the parse approach. What pieces of the above list do you have and where are they? Whether you do it or parse does it, all of those pieces are required by anyone who wants to symbolicate a crash log

Comment: @nhgrif - I have #2 and #3. As for #1 and #4, I don't know. Please understand: I am following the directions that Parse gives for its crash-reporting service. The directions are shallow - which is good in a way. Here's the key step:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
`cd <path_to_cloudcode_folder>`

`parse symbols <app_name_from_cloud_code_config_globals> --path="${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`

You add this as a Run Script phase to the Build Phases of your App. The rest is supposedly automatic. They provide manual directions as well, which is what I did in my question.

Comment: So there's no mention of crash logs, device symbol files, etc. Again, good in a way, but if you want to dig deeper, there's nothing there. So I'm trying to work with what Parse wants. If I weren't using Parse, then I'd be learning about the basic ways of doing crash reporting (no third-party services, IDE-related only), accessing logs, getting the symbol tables. So I can't answer your question fully because I don't know.

Comment: I am having this exact problem, did you ever find a solution?  Please let me know

Comment: Yes, Ditch Parse Crash Reporting. Use CrashLytics from Fabric (from Twitter); could not be easier, works like a charm, near-zero installation time. Best solution out there.